# Why won't this INSERT INTO statement work?

Tags: mysql

This is a pretty basic question, so apologies.

I have a simple SQL (MySQL5) table and I'm trying to command line insert data into it. But it keeps popping an error and I have no idea why.

This is my console output:

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS from queries;

+-------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+

| Field | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |

+-------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+

| id    | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |

| query | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |

| date  | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |

| match | int(11)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |

+-------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+

4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO queries (query, match) VALUES ('cheese', 4);

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match) VALUES ('cheese', 4)' at line 1

mysql>
```

What's going on? Why doesn't my INSERT INTO command work?

Answer (score 7):

`match` is a reserved MySQL word.

Try this instead (using backticks):

```
INSERT INTO queries (`query`, `match`) VALUES ('cheese', 4);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`match` is a keyword in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match).  You have to escape it (and it's a good idea to do this anyway):

```
INSERT INTO queries (`query`, `match`) VALUES ('cheese', 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have backtiks on match. match is a keyword in MySQL

```
 INSERT INTO queries (`query`, `match`) VALUES ('cheese', 4);
```

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html